# Tomcat manual load balancing: multiple domains or single one

Tags: tomcat, server, load-balancing

I hope this questione doesn't sound too trivial.

We develop a web application in SAAS style deployed with a Tomcat instance. 
In the same virtual machine are installed both the DB who server the app and Tomcat. The DB is in a multitenant configuration, with the same schema replicated for each our our customers, to preserve data integrity.

We were thinking of splitting this configuration installing another virtual machine to divide the number of customers between 2 machine instead of one, thus reducing the problems only to half of our customers in case one of the machine is out for maintenance and to better distribute resources; a sort of manual load balancing.

The problem is that if we do like this we should buy another domain for the new server and the new customers (we would insert only new customers in this new server) should type www.myapp2.com instead of the old www.myapp.com and this sounds ugly.

I took time to sketch a simple graph:

[image]

Maybe this can be resolved with another server responding at www.myapp.com who manage only the login data and then redirect the user to one of the 2 servers.

Or maybe we are just messing and we should seriously investigate in a proper load balancing solution with a proxy(not manual).

What is the best approach in modern industry?

Thanks